# Javascript - Script working only for one element

Tags: javascript, forms

I have to forms on my webpage, one with `name="login"` and the other one with `name="register"` (code below). I use javascript for alerts if the input fields are empty on submitting.
It worked well when I only had one form on the webpage, but the problem starts when I add the other form. It works fine for the first form (login) but when I fill in and submit the second one, it alerts that the fields are empty. (Supposedly, because the login fields are empty).
What's causing this and how do I fix this?

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="" name="login" onSubmit="return valid();">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="signin">Log inn</button>
</form>

<form method="post" action="index.php" name="register" onSubmit="return valid();">
        <label for="username">Username:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="username"><br>
        <label for="email">E-mail adress:</label><br>
        <input type="text" name="email"><br>
        <label for="password">Password:</label><br>
        <input type="password" name="password"><br>
        <button type="submit" name="signup">Registrer deg</button>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function valid()
  {
  if(document.login.username.value == "")
  {
  alert ("Please enter your username.")
  document.login.username.focus();
  return false;
  }
  if(document.login.password.value == "")
  {
  alert ("Please enter your password.")
  document.login.password.focus();
  return false;
  }
  }
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function valid()
  {
  if(document.register.username.value == "")
  {
  alert ("Please enter your username.")
  document.register.username.focus();
  return false;
  }
  if(document.register.email.value == "")
  {
  alert ("Please enter your e-mail adress.")
  document.register.email.focus();
  return false;
  }
  if(document.register.password.value == "")
  {
  alert ("Please enter your password.")
  document.register.password.focus();
  return false;
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are defining two separate functions with the same name, they are overwriting each other. Make two separate functions, `validateLogin` and `validateRegister`

```
<form method="post" action="" name="login" onSubmit="return validateLogin();"> ... 
<form method="post" action="" name="login" onSubmit="return validateRegister();">
```

A slight improvement to your code is for you to pass the form into the handler, so it makes your code shorter and uses fewer globals

```
<form method="post" action="" name="login" onSubmit="return validateLogin(this);"> ..

function validateLogin(form)
{
  if(form.username.value == "")
  {
    alert ("Please enter your username.")
    form.username.focus();
    return false;
  }
  if(form.password.value == "")
  {
    alert ("Please enter your password.")
    form.password.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

And even better, hookup your handlers through JS instead of HTML

```
//After the HTML is loaded, and give your form an ID
document.getElementById('loginForm').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    // In IE, the event is global
    e = e || window.event;
    // "this" points to the form
    if(this.username.value == "") {
        alert ("Please enter your username.")
        this.username.focus();
        return false; //  or e.preventDefault();
    }
    if(this.password.value == "") {
        alert ("Please enter your password.")
        this.password.focus();
        return false; //  or e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

And last but not least, you can abstract the work of checking for empty values so your two functions aren't doing the same work.

```
function createValidator(formId, validations) {
    var form = document.getElementById(formId);
    form.addEventListener('submit', function(e){
        e = e || window.event;
        for (var i=0; i < validations.length; i++) {
            var elementName = validations[i].elName;
            var errorMessage = validations[i].error; 
            if (form[elementName].value === "") {
                alert(errorMessage);
                return false; // or e.preventDefault()
            }
        }            
    });
}

// And set up both your handlers, remember to give your forms and ID
createValidator('formLogin', [{
    elName: 'username',
    error: 'Please enter your username'
}, {
    elName: 'password',
    error: 'Please enter your Password'
}]);

createValidator('formRegister', [{
    elName: 'username',
    error: 'Please enter your username'
},{
    elName: 'email',
    error: 'Please enter your email address'
},{
    elName: 'password',
    error: 'Please enter your Password'
}]);
```